# Cost of SQL commands: Select vs Update

Tags: sql

I am writing a program that accesses a database in order to make sure values are up to date. For example(this isn't my real issue), I have an object that has a unique property. I want to ensure that the database has that same unique value saved. If it doesn't, I want to update the database. This would happen in a script that runs in the background repeatedly to ensure that the value's stay synchronized.

So my question is, would it be more cost effective to SELECT the value and compare, then UPDATE. Or should I just UPDATE automatically?

I imagine the SELECT and compare might be more efficient then just updating all the time, but I don't know for certain.

Which should I go with?

Thanks (I apologize if this is a dumb question).

Comment: I was wondering if your program has exclusive access to the data in the DB or if it is shared between multiple programs or instances of your program. If it is the first I would synchronise the data in the application and any updates to that object aught to be persisted to the DB immediately.  If you share the data then you don't want to blindly update the database or you'll keep trashing each others data, in that case adding a version column which is incremented on update and the value is checked that it is still the same as a condition of update, then user decides if to replace data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good question. It needs a sound knowledge of SELECT and UPDATE queries.

UPDATE is used when you need to update existing records in a table with WHERE as to specify which record you need to update. so better to use UPDATE query.

As far as cost and time effective, you can use different query analyzer to analysis the queries.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET value to update
WHERE some condition to update
```

Answer (score 3):

I imagine you can do this with just one `UPDATE...WHERE` SQL call without having to make a `SELECT` call. This is the fastest way to do this.

```
UPDATE <table>
SET <data to update> 
WHERE <data is not up to date)
```